# Why does clang think gcc's subrange does not satisfy gcc's __ranges_begin function concept equirements?

Tags: c++, clang, c++20, c++-concepts, compiler-bug

The code that fails for clang (while gcc seems okey with it)

```
    int arr[] { 111, 222, 333};
    ranges::subrange(
        ranges::begin(arr),ranges::end(arr) );
```

It looks like clang claim gcc's subrange do not have begin function?!

```
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-snapshot/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11.0.0/../../../../include/c++/11.0.0/bits/iterator_concepts.h:953:35: note: and 'std::ranges::subrange<int *, int *, std::ranges::subrange_kind::sized> &' does not satisfy '__member_begin'

      requires is_array_v<_Tp> || __member_begin<_Tp&> || __adl_begin<_Tp&>

                                  ^

/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-snapshot/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11.0.0/../../../../include/c++/11.0.0/bits/iterator_concepts.h:937:33: note: because '__detail::__decay_copy(__t.begin())' would be invalid: no member named 'begin' in 'std::ranges::subrange<int *, int *, std::ranges::subrange_kind::sized>'

          { __detail::__decay_copy(__t.begin()) } -> input_or_output_iterator;

                                       ^

/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-snapshot/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11.0.0/../../../../include/c++/11.0.0/bits/iterator_concepts.h:953:59: note: and 'std::ranges::subrange<int *, int *, std::ranges::subrange_kind::sized> &' does not satisfy '__adl_begin'

      requires is_array_v<_Tp> || __member_begin<_Tp&> || __adl_begin<_Tp&>
```

[[LIVE](https://compiler-explorer.com/z/KzfzGP)]

---

part of gcc's [iterator_concepts.h](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-10.2.0/libstdc++/api/a00440_source.html#L882) :

```
   namespace __detail
   {
     template<typename _Tp>
       constexpr decay_t<_Tp>
       __decay_copy(_Tp&& __t)
       noexcept(is_nothrow_convertible_v<_Tp, decay_t<_Tp>>)
       { return std::forward<_Tp>(__t); }
  
     template<typename _Tp>
       concept __member_begin = requires(_Tp& __t)
         {
           { __detail::__decay_copy(__t.begin()) } -> input_or_output_iterator;
         };
  
     void begin(auto&) = delete;
     void begin(const auto&) = delete;
  
     template<typename _Tp>
       concept __adl_begin = __class_or_enum<remove_reference_t<_Tp>>
         && requires(_Tp& __t)
         {
           { __detail::__decay_copy(begin(__t)) } -> input_or_output_iterator;
         };
  
     // Simplified version of std::ranges::begin that only supports lvalues,
     // for use by __range_iter_t below.
     template<typename _Tp>
       requires is_array_v<_Tp> || __member_begin<_Tp&> || __adl_begin<_Tp&>
       auto
       __ranges_begin(_Tp& __t)
       {
         if constexpr (is_array_v<_Tp>)
           {
             static_assert(sizeof(remove_all_extents_t<_Tp>) != 0,
                           "not array of incomplete type");
             return __t + 0;
           }
         else if constexpr (__member_begin<_Tp&>)
           return __t.begin();
         else
           return begin(__t);
       }
  
     // Implementation of std::ranges::iterator_t, without using ranges::begin.
     template<typename _Tp>
       using __range_iter_t
         = decltype(__detail::__ranges_begin(std::declval<_Tp&>()));
  
   } // namespace __detail
```

Comment: This looks like clang instantiating constraints too early.

Comment: Any updates on this? Perhaps a bug report?

Comment: @KelemenMáté It seems clang has to use only its own `libc++` with `<ranges>`, not `stdlibc++`. The `<ranges>` has been supported since clang 13 => CE[[xT8xosj8o](https://compiler-explorer.com/z/xT8xosj8o)]. Though you can always come back to `range-v3` on github.

Comment: This is a known Clang bug: https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/44178

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom Well, it seems there is a patch already merged but a corperate regression rises due to commercial code amongst facebook and the intel compiler. I hope they sort their things out soon. [d483730d8c3f](https://reviews.llvm.org/rGd483730d8c3f)

Comment: This issue was solved in Clang 16: https://godbolt.org/z/fEeM5Tevf

Comment: @sandthorn The libc++ implementation of `<ranges>` was only partially supported in clang 13, the libc++ docs don't claim ranges support is complete until clang 15. Anyway, this was indeed a clang bug that has been fixed, so this question could be closed now (or self-answered).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments of the question, now this issue has been resolved already by `Clang 16` with both `libc++` and `libstdc++`

[[LIVE](https://compiler-explorer.com/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGe1wAyeAyYAHI%2BAEaYxBJcpAAOqAqETgwe3r56icmOAkEh4SxRMVxxdpgOqUIETMQE6T5%2BZZj2uQzVtQT5YZHRsbY1dQ2ZZYNdwT1FfaUAlLaoXsTI7BzmAMzByN5YANQma27EhsCYCvvYJhoAgpdXwQQ7LEzBEDO3JgDsVtc7vzvMbAU8SYyx2RyMpz2awAIjsFAR0CAQOCTmc1t8rn8dvcdrViCYAKxWAmwz4WHalOI7Mw00g7NYMz7Q/YYrEo05IhReCLsiC3LFs44ckBRYAvPFzdkKJGuCASnZvdH8v5Sznc3nmABseMJFg0hOhpC1OqJXANioxTNuHDmtE4BN4fg4WlIqE4bms1jhCyWmD2ZjWPFIBE0NrmAGsQDSAHQADjW8c1a0kaw%2BBIAnEm1vpOJJHaHXZxeNKNMHQ3M4LAYFBqxAkGgWPE6NFyJQG036DEtscuASNKWaLQCNFpRAIgWIsFagBPThByfMYjTgDyEW0FRD3F4DbYgmXDFos%2BdvCwES8wDcYlo0q3pCwTyM4mPd7wxA3eAAbhzn5hVBUvMOc68PcLQFrQeA8jOHhYAWBDEHgLBAXMVAGMACgAGp4JgADuy7xIwQEyIIIhiOwUhEfIShqAWuhxAYRgoJ6lj6BB0qwAC7ARKgSQEKQX4xNwHx5hWHEoPE8RoMQqB8X0cFeAw4Yiaw7AOG%2BMkxHJClKWwIBUCwvH8SAmmKaQECiVKH7ZoZxkzHMqDxG0N4ALTwug4ERPs0LuaYlhei5CKeT5ViWGYGg7E5y4AF7hU8SwIJ5CjhtOBjhpgTlMB%2BqgElwZjhQ5CBvkw6C8Kg/HwVgbGvAkhhhMpnA7Kosaak5mqSDs3ZGBSBLRhoPU7BA3lMRYMzFi077OBArjDE0pCBBMhTFFkSQpAI01LTkqTdAt0y2GNlQCB0QyeI0ejlPt7RjFtvQlAMnRraMnRXVMJRzAoPrLBItr2vmz5uhwDVNS1bUdcAXU9X1A0QUF1gjWWx4Vkgv7/kQZAUHKxBocoNW0EICCoNhTpBu2dBMG0WMhDjeMEwWxOdig9HAAA%2BsZpC09EoR1Rw26oI2zbEMuAG4/jToukjyBXBjN68GL1T4E6vD8MRojiORiuUSo6jPrR%2BjHIxvnMe5lVmXVXE8epc5CTapmicg4mSdJ1nEPJJnGzpqmYObNnW3VekGbJTtad7OkWVZ/vO7ZroOakzmuYFQ2heFy5cDFtTIPFMKJclTCpelmXZblTn5YVxWumVeAVfAkryY4bAACrcdelfzIsH2jHL5MtEL1PPthRzxEhOYcA6pAiyVnDYH%2ByAASQAPNa17UM/1Nn9R6%2Bs2DsuCEDP6xcLDm5aBHCCYEVfRVZGfaD3mpCIRfo%2BFlztggKW%2B9W5WiAgAsBDxABraTfgKPlz0GrEiKtpBq0UBrGiehe5MH7luL6Q8fouj%2BgLL%2BAEdioCoLPIGC9jhg16mFCAHheadn9IGPe5Y5hHxPjEKqdoOBXxvqWO%2Bf1ixPzhgfCMIACRrGjAyfhAjBGakHmsJBY8H4vwrLWWs9YeYdhbGjNmXYGa9n7HwOgw5iCjnHM%2BBcM5CJ6KXKudcDhCI7kYAQfch4CynnPJeWgjdbz3mOE%2BF0%2BA3yVC/DeUWk8AIrCDCBehLp3JHCXNBFYLo4IIQHihJgaFMI4TwgRW8wDlZkTAbICB1EtbcJ1gxaGBtWLwFdpxbi8JzaCWEkHFSdsSAOzDoHEpKA4Ie0duHapul9KewDi7cyQoFCWW6eHOyUcBAxwCjCApFgE4RWik5WKacEpJRSmlDKWUcp5QIAVY%2BJdSrRHKhySAcxgQFE5tg%2BeIN8EQ0NgiKZsMzptBcAwdwx0RizWeU9RacRsgrTSK8maPy2ifJ2g8qoYx7q7VaGCx681rqnXBf8%2BFMKChwt3s3X0n1B7DxYfVRqc9gaL17ODQhNz0B3N4JIqhOzT5cIvvQxh3DmEFlYY/Z%2B5ZTIyI/gBb%2BvFFFyL5hzHSHA8U4MuUSgh0t/4kEAXEVJpEJAEgolkzWLpdCKpgXAngCDsXMs4KgnlGCsEiouYS7qBCV78tIesAkFD4ZUpoZQBBDLb66ofiWDhYZSCRkkJqaMmp/UBsDYG6Q9DREj1dRSyhXqQBrG6pqMwpQaRcA0PGjQOVYwhs4GYXgiFk1Mt%2BkWD1UjinSOKbIkhCi2yWr6MAZNZh1FDhHJQHRLpDFHnnFOIxa4NxmJ5ruSxB4jxuMwGeC8V4bxBmcY%2BCJJ5Xzvi8QWMWfjCKBLAhBUJ05wmESiYheBfBUIYSwrhfChMFayBAekpVVEVU6CjHk4wQ0WIREqiMxynB/LoDjmvGZy4FApziksrOOc1n502dsoqJUy4VyOZC8afhJrPIhXNFFz11q/IhYCzasLUPNChQdBFGQZqgvw8iyYXzbpHUI0iuowKXrotbtqsR99zltWAMgZAFJeq5QgJvFGZDd6RrtaQahWBaFcLMLGP1kgCTxkEQI4R9Kc2MvDQWt17DJEcrLSAJdKNf61ExtjLup7WaWtJqkDulNha9orTEWtGh61KMFSsbmNnUFGcXZPCWaFC0ywRMEQtcrQFXsgTk%2BtDM9bBRsIbJu9k30cA/V%2ByLP6/3zNTunaEmcVm53WQXIuOzIP7PLocqqAca6YHrp4F99GyIDHboZqmxmNUD3oTq1TE9kYz2Nax9jnHozcdXpFukvHt4BgE0W%2B1onHWXyUy61TbC2VCcjMmaMGYuBrA0E1db/qCQEgU5wMNOKJHsrfid8t8jUZVps/THsmo1GDk0doicnb228DbcYntt5zF7kHTYkddjx2ESncAVxs6PGOAXT%2BXxgFbyrufCEqCGAZ3BngrurV%2B64mHsSSewigXL3gOvVA7M4WplPqNqJU25TDKVNfjbWpUkhmNJti0hnvSfZdLaYzuqIcWcR1i9Hd9rl3KeUGmvcKsdJnxzCrM/9iyM7LOzqsvOGzC5bOLgV4gByqsnNqkKljuDOpcF9eayGERyWwfOk8l5VG4jIbIztTDq1EXfOWkC7D5HiMXTuk783bRDrjBQ%2B7gjJ0Ho0bd9MV670yKMZU8g3FgMTV4MN8S/qIvIu2s4cJ6lYno0pj9RoD4Zh0zpqEhoQMaw9sMJm/m2PamFsH007ARGUOSB6clhZ9zn3TNk3q1ZzvV2QaG7UY5zmLnztuYax5ioXmpazUnrLfzD9ccKuC9k1VMb70ResKT4p5Oyl%2BwElwS22kakSTqTzjp7tz9NN9lfvpEIBmhw0j03noyGDjLchBYXUMhpi4mdCKZP6cyCy6WmWCu2WoGKu4GuyUGxWVcggCE5WDcVWb0LcNWrkwQ7eE%2Bt4LS7ApYTWe6LWTGf07WU8fGXW%2BuoMSexuA2W%2BG8UqxA/G6enqImNK0218ymh282420aZgHw0YkgKYEmResa9m6YsYsYIiRBhaGmJ2nKSiv8Si12Rgg%2BA4GiTaY4T2i4L2pAb23apife/aViQ6J4f2Y6DiE6JhD4wOSO7i8634PiyM/iwEggoEcO66COMEz4O6MSB6CSx6ySQYS%2BqsmSBOOSIausJO0W7EJse%2BFSh%2BVSTStsp%2B9OHOrObszOqRx%2BnS%2B%2BRkz%2BHS3OmRr6/O8Wgun%2BMIpKUyv%2Bn6Eu36UuUUMuIB8uwGSuuWqu%2BWpchW0GVU2uTmce%2BKFBFIRu1yrEtyQ09ye0jyCGVuwe7y6AtGaGbQGGLuWGAeIKEx0KlGMxHufu8xIe9Q3u8IpG20dGKBGKaKhBMe4ieuYqQxJKIxZKYxgmGeLB2eS23U6Y6YGgkgHwmoXAnx3xvx6Ymale7Bs2NeXBMhnKOmLeaM%2BmCgmBveRMXe5mPe3cSJ/eKit2pYw%2BQqo%2BfM4%2BveDh4sksPmc%2Bfm8sFEF6y%2B%2BOIWa%2B4R%2BSj6URUAu%2BZsVO8RNOdUSR9st%2BnJGRDSaR7AN%2BmR%2BR/SgyhRkccWH6Qu5R9xlRCWNRSWdRQBaWgGWWIGyueWEGHRGuRWVWpWCBFWjcMGpxrctWGBqJxmOB7C%2BBaOFxh2JB08DB5BNxyeRCj6dBW8DBO8TBh8WeU2imoJ1e4iEJUaS2fBmYBIkg9mAYKYXxO2iqoaUhR2i2IAkgXAK2UZ2UAhu2oUAYQkg82a7Bealx98Txnq9ChZnB3B/EyQzgkgQAA%3D)]