# Using iterator to retrieve const values pointed to in containers

Tags: c++, iterator, c++17, const-correctness, const-pointer

[Const casting container value-types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19122858/why-is-a-vector-of-pointers-not-castable-to-a-const-vector-of-const-pointers) seems not possible. A comment in the other question suggests iterators as a solution, yet does not go into detail.
Since I seemingly cannot simply convert a container from a non-const to a const version as a function parameter, I arrive at Iterators to maybe be able to do the job.

I actually have a `vector<shared_ptr<Thing> >` to be treated as `const vector<shared_ptr<Thing const> >`.
With it I intend to use the `shared_ptr<Thing const>` as further references in other structures, without allowing those structures to alter the `Thing`s. Those structures may create their own objects, stored by their own shared_ptr, if they want slightly different content within their containers, while still actively sharing most `Things` with other objects.

So I would need either `shared_ptr<const Thing>&`, or `const shared_ptr<const Thing>&` from an Iterator through the sequence. Either would suffice, but just because one can be indifferent about passing references in this example, because of shared_ptr's copy semantics are about just that.
Yet even just using default `const_iterator`, retrieved by `cbegin()`,`c.end()` and such, will give me a `const shared_ptr<Thing>&` instead.

Edit: To copy the vector element for element would be one way technically, as in the other question, yet undesired for interface reasons. I am going for reinterpretation here, not copy.

Any suggestions on where a workaround might lie?

Comment: the issues you describe would be more clear with some code. Code says more than thousand words

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Code, which describes the general intention is provided in the linked question above. I'll rearrange some things in the question to let it take focus. As to what code would look like to solve it, well that is the question.

Comment: the question should be selfcontained. If the code in some other question is the basis of your question then add it in the question (with proper attribution of course)

Comment: do you refer to "call it via `fn({vc.begin(), vc.end()})`, requesting an explicit conversion" when you say "A comment in the other question suggests iterators as a solution, yet does not go into detail" ? There is not much detail to say about it. It just calls the constructor of `std::vector<const Thingy*>`  so the function cannot modify the `Thingy`s.

Comment: There's no low cost workaround here.  If you need to pass an argument of `vector<shared_ptr<Thing const>>`, but you have a `vector<shared_ptr<Thing>>` you'll need need to build the argument.  I'd provide a helper factory function `vector<shared_ptr<Thing const>> to_const(vector<shared_ptr<Thing>> const& v) {/*code*/}`.

Comment: Well, iterators can invalidate – what, if a new instance is added at runtime, or if some objects are removed? Note that `end` gets invalid on adding elements even if no re-allocation occurs. Thus can iterators be a solution? Only if you don't ever modify the vector afterwards – apart from exchanging the elements contained in the shared pointers...

Comment: @Eljay That would introduce other trouble, e.g. trying to buffer the vector would lead to not receiving updates of the original source...

Comment: Do you actually need the shared ownership? Otherwise, maybe something like indirect_value<> (proposed) could fit.

Comment: @JeffGarrett The way I set up my Data-Structures here is based on shared ownership, yes, or at least it is a feature here. Wether I could do it without or not is a different thing entirely. I guess I could use the proposed structure in 5-10 years, but I don't see how I wouldn't get to the same problem in green. I could also have raw pointers here instead of smart ones. Same difference.

Comment: It isn't entirely a different thing. If shared ownership is part of the desired interface, const access through a const path (i.e. the question) isn't logical. A copy can subvert that; it protects little. (ptr->mutate() isn't allowed, but ptr2 = ptr; ptr2->mutate() is and has the same effect) If shared_ptr happened to be a convenient choice for some reason, but shared ownership isn't essential... if you want a vector of value-like things, where const is propagated, but they are stored on the heap, you can generalize that with something like `propagate_const<>` or `indirect_value<>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your situation, it sounds like defining a custom iterator with the semantics you want is the safe and simple way to go. It's technically correct, hard to accidentally misuse, and fairly fast, just requiring a `shared_ptr` copy on iterator dereference.

I always recommend `boost::iterator_facade` or `boost::iterator_adaptor` for creating an iterator type. Since it will contain the original `vector` iterator as a "base" implementation, `iterator_adaptor` is helpful.

```
class const_Thing_ptr_iterator :
    public boost::iterator_adaptor<
        const_Thing_ptr_iterator,                            // CRTP derived type
        std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Thing>>::const_iterator, // base iterator type
        std::shared_ptr<const Thing>,                        // value_type
        std::random_access_iterator_tag,                     // traversal type
        std::shared_ptr<const Thing>                         // reference
    >
{
public:
    const_Thing_ptr_iterator() = default;
    explicit const_Thing_ptr_iterator(base_type iter)
        : iterator_adaptor(iter) {}
};
```

The `reference` iterator type would be `std::shared_ptr<const Thing>&` by default, but in this case it can't be a reference since there is no object of that type. Normally the class would define some of the behavior functions like `dereference` or `increment`, but none are needed here: the only change from the base vector iterator is to the return type of `operator*`, and the default `reference dereference() const { return *base_reference(); }` works fine by implicit conversion from `const std::shared_ptr<Thing>&` to `std::shared_ptr<const Thing>`.

The class could also be a template taking `Thing` as its type parameter, to create multiple iterator types.

Then to provide a container-like view object, we can use C++20's `std::ranges::subrange` to provide `begin()` and `end()` and a few other things helping the out the range templates:

```
#include <ranges>
class const_Thing_ptrs_view
  : public std::ranges::subrange<const_Thing_ptr_iterator>
{
public:
    explicit const_Thing_ptrs_view(const std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Thing>> &vec)
        : subrange(const_Thing_ptr_iterator(vec.begin()),
                   const_Thing_ptr_iterator(vec.end())) {}
};
```

Or if that's not available, a simple class with `begin()` and `end()`:

```
class const_Thing_ptrs_view {
public:
    explicit const_Thing_ptrs_view(const std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Thing>> &vec)
        : m_begin(vec.begin()), m_end(vec.end()) {}
    const_Thing_ptr_iterator begin() const { return m_begin; }
    const_Thing_ptr_iterator end() const { return m_end; }
private:
    const_Thing_ptr_iterator m_begin;
    const_Thing_ptr_iterator m_end;
};
```

[Demo on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGe1wAyeAyYAHI%2BAEaYxCBmZqQADqgKhE4MHt6%2BekkpjgJBIeEsUTFxtpj2eQxCBEzEBBk%2BflzllWk1dQQFYZHRsS0KtfWNWQNDXcE9xX1mXACUtqhexMjsHOYAzMHI3lgA1CYbbgBumA4kh9gmGgCCm9u7mAdHbCwkAJ6X13dmWww7Xn2hzcEVQyQIAHpCNEmERiFCCDC4QB9JjoJgJOEAOgQCQSX1u3x2TAUCj2ABUEMFgAcAOxWW4JLwRWh4ZAgb57Ll7Y6oPDoPbIBCGYCYCBzOlWWkAEU53OCBB5Yi8YolaAYg0le2ImAIywYey4hwsdNlhJlxu%2BRIMpMFAkGyMp1ORmOIyOhxFhJD2HNu3L2TJZbL2oPBIBAHq9brRGLhwLl/q56odTqMLoIbsjcNIidzefzXIhEL2bgASuTlHssMQ8KcBQR3glMAnE4N0OHTudiMC2%2BGFMKdeh092jqngF8Nthw8mCO7EZ7s3siyGSU8s96G02W/7eyB%2B3VMEPXcCZxSqUZLjmC9f/cvjsrMMjN82/Xnd56GOhUCxUchVqS5yREgnyYYArxvfNlwzJhTmIBQxD2Z9t25Xd90HYcT3tRUx0uCC8OXHUqGiRhVhbAk7npb5A1ZdkWxnR1z2AYdAIXEhxWeaUq0wKgmC8WgCEtV8uUwVQEhowg7Q1Wcx2Y9diAgCJVyfRs13nOZkK5EA9jk1F0UxNiPQlExKItc1ZQ2Bk7kJX48CoPZkWRZAxK8BRnLJCdOLMDQvO8q1rL%2BAEgSOD9RQUcjiVteiZNdBRkWOPBMAAdzlLTqODd8RUwBQ%2B2ZELmyOKLGNk%2Bco3I4zLLS2ihL2ESxLZCTCudGK4oSxKIFPXdOzjI5UIHQ8MNHRiJ2wA4zAANk7dTqv9LSFFyzL2qwhimozFiowgTssSiYBgnFBYNIgxq01dNa4Q2s4sVcPajJMs0KPMyzNgqJQ/JuCKySOpjmvipLJSo5kaN9G5/Vq8TFU%2B4dYp%2BtqOoIdsQC6i4erhvs%2BqPDNgRwydcPMCazim4G8y0n9tt2zbSYYPacx/K7NquuYbqlO7/Qhk65JDTAdsptUsK1HU9WIA0Sc54JjVNOilui1b2fpyTNXK7VdX1PYac/MXjLuhIa3vREgZZyWirZkq4RV5EKcEwmkwNlbM2N71VfQC2Nad35XFs16FRVphdoJ8qW06s5urcXqD3Rkc3Cxq5Jx5C3/WOLEmX7M2mGQABrCBdxYJhU8fNDD0xobJz22PuXjxOEGTtOM5RkAs5z5E88dwbqUuYuLNe/1%2BGIPYIF4ohRrG3HXR9OXpMNjModajaGbIyjpu5V0AFpLnvbxVRL3NlyXy4hQW9SLMLYtT2iYgLmq52zO%2BDgFloTgAFZeD8DgtFIVBODcaxrD2BQlhWJ5Nh4KQAgmhr4LFTiAO%2BAAOLEGxJB328lwDQGxaSQLGpArgY0776E4JIR%2BIDX6cF4NlDQQCQELDgLAGAiAQAiTOF4bMFBe7EGAAoZQhgKhCAQKgRKT9AFoBYAkOgsI0hsJCLQTh3Cn4v34YI%2BgMRjhOQSHFLgABOZEBhEQOlUKg0gMi6DRAAPL0IkTw/BtDkA3GYdlDgvBzE1HwE/Xg/BBAiDEOwKQMhBCKBUOoZ%2BOg9AGCMCgT%2Blh9B4AiNlWAzA2AgFDIMUgsEEZOVTsABmr9MRpGsRCXsphLDWA0VlRUEImzEBYHgUktZMCLyXAAdVwYsZYqw9BtmCKIjhXDTHcF4BmTAaxAGJU9AkMh2COAP1IFI3gb8ODYFUHQk22ixoqwUAonkqisQFM1BAD%2BeTQl7FwIQb0AC5jdLIWAkAGwNgwNgWYSBkC4G3I0Cou%2BGwRn1JYCASQtIYFcEgRoDQtIxpjRuRsO%2BZgsETIITY2wIASHAL8eQqhEAkDmPoSQcglA6gsLaeIjpvDeB6I0SI9hOLJH4IJX0YAXBZi6O/LIwxxjcVmNmRYqxhDSB2LhsENlzjhCiHEB4nl3i1D4N0PEQJxgQk2FZBE%2BAEBonsDiQQBJfRuC0hUaA9JVRrGLzbIcaUuSrCWC8nsReTZ0SCGDIvGpYhaAmpqSJaCRDf5NLGA47FJi8VAJ1H03gAyMTDNvqMvBfjIUzLmd6BZi8xqSD2MAP8hozBYi4D3bZhqbB7PwCbI5Jz4ULAQJgNEfRxSvN4O80FWI0GqJUb8ZBGDPngvwVMohMLSG5tIOAyQXAK130kColBKigVcA2D8kFIyNjBpfk21tWg0mBrMBOyZbK4UzoWLBFIzhJBAA%3D%3D%3D). (Clang doesn't like the ranges code due to [this libstdc++ incompatibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64300832/why-does-clang-think-gccs-subrange-does-not-satisfy-gccs-ranges-begin-functi); I'm not sure how to get godbolt to switch it to clang's libc++.)

Comment: Since a simple reinterpretation seems out of the picture, I can see how your solution is the most sound way to do it. One can cast the pointer type on the dereference and has the behavior safely tucked away.

Answer (score 1):

A pretty simple approach might be maintaining a vector of pointers to `const` already internally – and casting the `const` away on internal usage.

**Warning:** Don't consider this as an invitation for doing so carelessly! If you do so, at some point of time you *will* break something. After all those objects are `const` for a reason!

In given case, though, this reason is a pure external one – if it wasn't for the public interface the objects wouldn't ever have got `const` anyway so casting it away again is valid *in this very specific case*.

```
class DataOwner
{
public:
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Thing const>> const& data() const
    {
        return m_data;
    }

    void modify()
    {
        m_data.emplace_back(new Thing());

        at(0)->doSomething();
    }

    // for convenience of the user you might optionally duplicate
    // the const interface of `std::vector` here as well

private:
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Thing const>> m_data;

    Thing* at(size_t index)
    {
        // only one single location where const-casting
        // remember: generally a dangerous operation,
        // here one of the view valid use cases
        return const_cast<Thing*>(m_data[index].get());
        // don't forget to document in your own code WHY it is valid here
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Copying around all the shared pointers into new vectors can become pretty expensive quickly, especially if the original source vector gets updated frequently and referring instances thus need to fetch updates again and again.

I personally would thus rather provide either a wrapper around `std::vector` or around `std::shared_ptr` that give modifying access only to the data owner (who would be a friend then) while the general interface only allows non-modifying access. Wrapping the vector, though, will require the shared pointers to get copied whenever retrieving one, thus involving reference counting, additionally the solution gets more complex, thus going with the wrapper around the shared pointer here:

```
struct Thing
{
    void doSomething() { }
    void doSomethingElse() const { }
};

class DataOwner
{
public:
    class SharedPointer
    {
    public:
        SharedPointer(SharedPointer const&) = default;
        SharedPointer(SharedPointer&&) = default;
        SharedPointer& operator=(SharedPointer const&) = default;
        SharedPointer& operator=(SharedPointer&&) = default;

        Thing const& operator*() const
        {
            return *m_data;
        }
        Thing const* operator->() const
        {
            return m_data.get();
        }
        Thing const* get() const
        {
            return m_data.get();
        }

        // should be all of the public interface needed...

    private:
        friend class DataOwner;

        SharedPointer(Thing* t) : m_data(t) { }
        std::shared_ptr<Thing> m_data;
    };

    std::vector<SharedPointer> const& data() const
    {
        return m_data;
    }

    void modify()
    {
        m_data.emplace_back(SharedPointer(new Thing()));

        m_data[0].m_data->doSomething();
        // if needed at many places you might want to have a
        // convenience function, see below...
        at(0)->doSomething();
    }

    // for convenience of the user you might optionally duplicate
    // the const interface of `std::vector` here as well

private:
    std::vector<SharedPointer> m_data;

    Thing* at(size_t index)
    {
        return m_data[index].m_data.get();
    }
};

int main()
{
    DataOwner o;
    o.modify();

    o.data()[0]->doSomethingElse();
    // o.data()[0]->doSomething(); won't compile!

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It seems, this way every `DataOwner` has access to every instance of `SharedPointer`. A weaker restriction. Could work, hardly ideal. Reimplementing pointer type not ideal either. However I suspect some pattern hidden at the basis of your answer that would point to an alternative way to design my code, it is however, too late here for me to see it just now.

Comment: @Meph Well, indeed, cross-access is possible. To be honest, I silently assumed one single data owner... Agree, too, on the separate pointer type being a disadvantage. You *could* maintain internally a `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Thing const>>` – and cast the `const` away on internal usage. Didn't present as it could be interpreted as invitation for doing so carelessly...