# Why does calling std::ranges::rotate on a vector result in a "no matching function call to '__begin'" error using clang 15?

Tags: c++, c++20, clang++, compiler-bug

I have the following function that does a rotation to a vector of char :

```
void rotate()
{
    std::ranges::rotate(_right, _right.begin() + 1);
}
```

_right is defined as :

```
 std::vector<char> _right;
```

trying to compile it with clang 15, it complains that (https://godbolt.org/z/7ovTfxe31):

```
 no matching function for call to '__begin'
```

the reason for that seems to be the following :

```
in instantiation of template type alias 'iterator_t' requested here
  requires contiguous_iterator<iterator_t<_Derived>>
```

but I assume that vector is a contiguous container. Code compiles and run with GCC.

Here are my questions:

1. According to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/ranges/rotate) the above mentioned call should be a legitimate call or am I missing sth?
2. If it is a legitimate call then is there any way to make the clang to accept the call like GCC?

Comment: I remember clang 15's ranges implementation was busted. See: https://stackoverflow.com/q/64300832/5754656 . If you can't use clang 16 or above, try ranges-v3 (or give up on using ranges)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

clang 15 and older compilers have issues with compiling libstdc++ algorithms due to how constraints are checked for satisfaction.

See [LLVM Issue 44178: [concepts] deferred substitution into requirements of class template members not implemented](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/44178). This is a known bug and has been resolved in clang 16.

Unlike GCC, clang doesn't defer instantiation of member constraints until member instantiation.
In [libstdc++'s `__begin`](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/3a7dd24eadeb918f9990db7adcb3e63e76bd63fb/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/iterator_concepts.h#L994-L1006), the constraint `__member_begin` is not satisfied on the `std::subrange` created from the vector by `std::rotate` despite `std::subrange` obviously having a `.begin()` member. As a result, `std::rotate` can't be called.